# How can i get same checkout fields in mobile application

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am finishing my mobile application and now in the checkout screen, i want to show the same fields as i configure in woocommmerce store, i.e: default country, required fields cities value etc.

Similarly i am looking a way to get the same shipping rules i set for online store, so on preview i can show the same value.

Is there any way i can achieve this?? i looked into the documentation as in below mentioned link, but it does not shows how can i retrieve the configuration data for checkout.

http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-properties

Appreciate community help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is not possible, you would need to create a custom plugin that creates a new endpoint and using these hooks you get checkout fields and list them:

```
$address_fields = apply_filters('woocommerce_billing_fields', $address_fields);
$address_fields = apply_filters('woocommerce_shipping_fields', $address_fields);
```

You can find more info at: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/